# Magento 2 : Redirect external url in controller with specific header

Tags: redirect, controller, magento2

I need to redirect to some external url with  specific header from my controller.
I tried to use setHeader on my redirect object but it seems my header is not passed cause i receive a 401 response. If i do a test with a guzzle object, just to check, headers are ok.
So how can i redirect to an external url passing headers parameters in a controller ?
My code :

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Controller\Hipe;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use \Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class Redirect implements HttpGetActionInterface
{

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    private $logger;

    private \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session;

    private \Myvendor\Mymodule\Helper\Data $helper;

    private \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $redirectFactory;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory, PageFactory $resultPageFactory,\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session, \Packitoo\Hipe\Helper\Data $helper, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->redirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn()){
            $customerId = $this->session->getCustomer()->getId();
                
            $token = $this->helper->getToken($customerId);
            $redirect = $this->redirectFactory->create();
            $redirect->setHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " . $token, true);
            $redirect->setPath('https://myexternalurl');
            return $redirect;   
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head and tbh only slightly different.  Also have you tries setting a different header e.g. Content-Type to see if you ccan change anything?

```
public function __construct(
    //...
    Magento\Framework\Controller\Result $rawResultFactory,
    //...        
)
{
    $this->rawResultFactory = $rawResultFactory;
}
public function execute()
{
    if ($this->session->isLoggedIn()){
        $customerId = $this->session->getCustomer()->getId();
                
        $token = $this->helper->getToken($customerId);
        $redirect = $this->rawResultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $redirect->setHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " . $token, true);
        $redirect->setPath('https://myexternalurl');

        return $redirect;   
        }
}
```

Comment: I ended up with a call in basic curl inside execute and retrieving the headers to isolate url redirected. and then put it in setPath.
I will post the code